# Server runs out of RAM - How to make more efficient?

Tags: memory, ram

My website seems to go down for up to an hour almost every day. I don't know much about servers so would appreciate advice on what to do next.

The website (3dsbuzz.com) has a Wordpress section, Wiki, Gallery and a VBulletin forum each with their own custom code and plug-ins. So there are lots of potential places which could be inefficiently coded. It runs from a cloud server with 2GB of RAM. The MySQL database is 370MB. We get around 30,000 page views per day.

What would be the best way to reduce the amount of down time? Should I upgrade my server (I can't really afford to) or is 2GB reasonable? I have plenty of errors in my error log, but they don't always occur around the same times as the server going down, so I'm not sure how relevant it is.

Comment: Unless you can find out *why* it goes down, all changes are pretty much just guesswork.

Comment: Is there any way I can narrow down what is causing the problem/s?

Comment: Yes, but given that you're not the developer who built this, you're probably on the wrong site for this. http://serverfault.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I've asked on Serverfault http://serverfault.com/questions/308516/server-runs-out-of-ram-how-to-find-cause (in case anyone wants to follow this up)

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to remove each conponent one by one until the server no longer crashes.

Then, you know where to look for and can investigate further.

Comment: I agree with this, delta debugging is a way to go.